# What image augmentations can help a neural network identify the lowest-value pixels within an image?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I am training a CNN to identify objects, and I believe the network will learn much faster if it can learn to focus on the pixels with the lowest value. One way to go about this would be to augment the images before training. What augmentations would work best in this case?

Comment: It possible that this question is too imprecise to be answered properly. To me, it's not clear what you are trying to do. Also: aren't all pixels in an image the same size?

Comment: @applesoup Please let me know how I can improve my question. I am talking about pixel values and not size. Typically black colors have values of 0 and while colors have values close to 1.

Comment: So then if you think that helps, what have you tried? Not incredibly complex to just set every pixel >0.1 (or any other threshold) to 1 and see what happens. Note, however, that this is an operation that can easily be learned by adjusting the bias, so if this is a winning strategy, you should see that in the high biases and negative edge weights of your first layer. Check your net before you wreck your net!